# Decode an array of messages in protobuf.js

Tags: node.js, protobuf.js

In our node.js application we need to deserialize a Buffer which we know contains multiple objects. With `protobuf-net` this was done like so:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(byteData);
List<Schema.Object> objects = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<List<Schema.Object>>(stream);
```

I am now trying to do the same with `protobuf.js`. I haven't found an example where it creates an array of the model objects, only a single model object, like so:

```
const Object = root.lookupType('model.Object');
const message = Object.decode(byteData); //this creates one object but the buffer contains multiple objects
```

How do you create an array of objects, rather than a single object using protobuf.js?

Here's how the data is being serialized:

```
try
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, objects);
            Stream.Position = 0;

            // Return the serialized byte array.
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    finally {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. You can wrap the Object with another message containing a repeated entry. Then when it's decoded, it will be an array of Objects.

In the .proto file:

```
message ObjectCollection {
  repeated Object objects = 1;
}
```